# SQLite Problems in GCC compiler. - C programming

Tags: c, sqlite, gcc

Hey I am a new programmer in C and I am using Linux which has the GCC compiler so I was previously facing the issue that GCC could not find sqlite3.h as a directory and thankfully that got solved but now the problem is that when I use `sqlite3_close` it says `undefined reference sqlite3_close`. Please help.

Any help will be appreciated.
*THANK YOU*

Comment: add `-lsqlite3` to your link command

Comment: In my link command... Do you mean where the code links to the database? Do you mean here > `sqlite3_open("test.db", &db);` @Jean-FrançoisFabre

Comment: no, there are several phases when building an executable. Compilation _then_ link.

Comment: finding the dupe target after googling "undefined reference sqlite3 site:stackoverflow.com"

Answer (score 0):

There is a reference to this problem in [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/556043/not-able-to-include-sqlite3-in-c-program)

Try adding `-lsqlite3` to the compiler command.

Here is an example:

```
g++ mail.cpp -lsqlite3
```

Comment: Tried. did not work. But no error as well!